# how to calculate the winning special offer

Tags: algorithms

This is surely way below the level of maths questions you normally get on here but please humor me!

I have written a simple app that compares beer offers and works out the best (cheapest) price per 100ml. It works it out using the calculation written below:

```
function getPricePer100ml(cansize, cansinpack, numberofpacks, cost) {
  var totalCans = cansinpack * numberofpacks;
  var totalMl = totalCans * cansize;
  var total100Mls = totalMl / 100;
  return cost / total100Mls;
}
```

I run this twice to get each offers price per 100ml and then the lowest price "wins".

The issue I am having is understanding what I need to do on top of this to factor in the ABV (strength) of the beer. This is in % so for example:

```
offer1per100ml = 0.65p - 3.8%ABV
offer2per100ml = 0.75p - 5.2%ABV
```

My app would class offer 1 as the winner because its cheaper per 100ml but I suspect that you get more bang for your buck by paying the extra 10p and buying the strong stuff.

How can I write this mathematically? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Right now you're computing the cost per 100ml. Instead you could be computing the cost per ml of alcohol. If you take the total number of ml and multiply by ABV, then you get the number of mls of alcohol. Dividing as you did before will indicate the cheapest way to get wasted.

Comment: Why isn't taste somehow figured in this?!

Comment: We're calculating in the GWQ metric

Comment: haha thanks I'll try plugging that in tonight - is that the get wasted quickest metric? :)